# Subview fade in and fade out help

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I am having a problem fading out my subview. I have no trouble fading the view in but fading out ..just drops the view.

```
-(void)flipToReview {
ReviewViewController *reviewVariable = [[ReviewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ReviewViewController" bundle:nil];
[self setReviewViewController:reviewVariable];
self.ReviewViewController.view.alpha =0;
[UIView beginAnimations:@"flipview" context:nil]; 
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:_window cache:YES];
[reviewVariable release];    
[self.window addSubview:self.ReviewViewController.view];
self.ReviewViewController.view.alpha =1;

[UIView commitAnimations];
}


-(void)flipBackFromReview {
//   self.ReviewViewController.view.alpha = 1;

[UIView beginAnimations:@"trip" context:nil]; 
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];

[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:_window cache:NO];
self.ReviewViewController.view.alpha = 0;
[self.ReviewViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
[UIView commitAnimations];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
[self.ReviewViewController.view setHidden:1];
NSLog(@"remove subview"); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move:

```
[self.ReviewViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
```

That cannot be done "over time" in an animation. What you want to do is move that to a selector and use `setAnimationDelegate` and `setAnimationDidStopSelector`. Put the following in your animation block:

```
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(finshedFadeOut)];
```

Then make the following method:

```
- (void)finshedFadeOut {
    [self.ReviewViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try the following:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^{ ReviewViewController.view.alpha = 0.0;}
                 completion:^(BOOL fin) {
                 if (fin) [ReviewViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
                 }];
```

Comment: These are blocks. Blocks are basically pieces of code that can be dealt with for special purposes(like Multitasking). Have a look in the Dev Resources from Apple!

Comment: I really should upvote this since your answer is definitely better than the accepted one.

Comment: Hey.. I did this and it works great.  But since I don't completely understand what's going on here.  Do you add this after the commitAnimations of the other style as a way of removing the view when it's done?  Or does this do the entire fade and everything?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well, the way I got around it was changing the alpha to 0, instead of just removing the view. That can be animated.

Comment: @Julian Since I can't comment directly on Julians answer, I'll do it here. What do those ^ symbols mean in your code?